# Sort a NSMutableArray in objective-c?

Tags: xcode, sorting, nsmutablearray

I am working on NSMutable Array containing list of "First Name" in it.I want to sort it alphabatically.

I tried this code

```
NSSortDescriptor * sortFriend = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:kfirstName ascending:YES] autorelease];
NSArray * descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortFriend];
NSArray * sorted = [Friendsarr sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

correct me if i am wrong.I do have an array of names also if that could be used.

Thanks

---

I tried the code

```
NSSortDescriptor * sortFriend = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:kfirstName ascending:YES  selector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease];
NSArray * descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortFriend];
NSArray * arrmp = [temparray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

But still my result contain 2 'k' chars. one 'k' and 'K'.I want to have case insensitive result

Comment: What is your question? Doesn't this code work?

Comment: I just want to sort nsmutable array alphabetically this code doesnt work on my part

Comment: What is in your array? The code sample here assumes it contains dictionaries, is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

If your NSMutableArray only contains objects of type NSString, simply do:

```
[myMutableArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Comment: and ur method compare: here refers to...? Do i have to compare string at every index with every other index

Comment: No it will automatically sort the array alphabetically

Comment: HI, I found the solution of sorting nsmutable array with sample code

Answer (score 1):

> You can sort NSMutable array case insensitively by this code

```
 NSSortDescriptor *sorter=[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:nil ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]autorelease];
                NSArray *sortdescriptor=[NSArray arrayWithObject:sorter];
                [cpy_arr_Service_Name sortUsingDescriptors:sortdescriptor];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of sorting `NSMutableArray`s with sample code which can be found on the site below.

http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/12/10/implementing-uitableview-sections-from-an-nsarray-of-nsdictionary-objects/

I hope it help others to as it provides indexed sorting of a grouped table view using an array as the datasource